# dojox email validator always fails

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

I'm trying to use a dijit/form/ValidationTextBox with an isEmailAddress validator to check for valid emails, the problem is that valid emails are flagged as invalid.

Note I got the validator to work by including "dojox/validate/web", but the form always evaluates to invalid in my login function

my code is:
HTML:

```
  <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="FormLogin">
    ...
    <input type="text" required="true" name="email" data-dojo-attach-point="tbEmail"
                                   data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                                   validator="dojox.validate.isEmailAddress"
                                   invalidmessage="Not a valid email" />

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
                                data-dojo-attach-point="LogInButton" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:Login">
                            Login
                        </button>
    ...

    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/Dialog",
  "dijit/form/Form",
  "dijit/registry",
  "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
  "dojox/validate",
  "dojox/validate/web",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
  "dojo/text!Templates/LoginForm.htm"
], function (
     declare, Dialog, Form, registry, ValidationTextBox, validate, web, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin,
     _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, LoginFrmTpl) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: LoginFrmTpl,
        postCreate: function () {

        },
        Login: function () {
            if (registry.byId("FormLogin").validate == true) { //this never evaluates to true, even when the email is valid
                alert("we can submit the data")
            }
            else {
                alert("error in form")
            }


        }

    });
});
```

Any ideas? The invalid message appears no matter what text is entered in tbEmail

Thanks

Comment: completely random guess, try `.validate()`

Comment: that throws an error: dojox.validate is not a function

Comment: Can you show more of your javascript? Are there any errors in the console when loading your page?

Comment: I posted my complete javascript.  I got the validator to work by including "dojox/validate/web", but when I try to validate the form in my login function it always says the form is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by validating the textbox tbEmail.  I changed my Login function to the following:

```
Login: function () {
            if (registry.byId("tbEmail").isValid() == true) {
                alert("we can submit the data")
            }
            else {
                alert("error in form")
            } 
        }
```